# Linux "ls -sh" command error in (corrupt?) folder print outs many blank spaces?

Tags: linux, ls, command, corruption

I am working with some disorganized data on a server. For a couple of the folders when I use the command:

```bash
ls -sh
```

To list files and file sizes, the seems to be an error where the cursor starts running and numerous blank lines are printed out. This only happens for some of the folders.

If I use (below) for the questionable folders, things do print/list out ok.

```bash
ls -lh
```

Could this mean that the folder is corrupt? Why is `ls -sh` causing such an issue?

Comment: Does `ls -sh | od-c` show any non-printable characters?